# pivot table relationship Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following relation:

1. **RAB** hasMany products.
2. **products** belongsToMany RAB

but this **products** also hasMany ***currency*** that belongsToOne **RAB** itself.
it looks like this.

[image: table]

in RAB model:

```
  public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ModelKeuangan\ProductsModel', 'rab_products', 'rab_id', 'products_id');
    }
```

in products model:

```
public function rab()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ModelUnitKerja\Perencanaan\RabModel', 'rab_products', 'products_id', 'rab_id');
    }
```

**rab_products** is my intermediate/join table.

it works just fine when im syncing products data for RAB. but i cant get how to make eloquent model for syncing **Currency** data to rab and products.

**do i need to make model for currency too? if yes, how do i define it?**

my plan is make a pivot like this, but can i make relation inside pivot table?

```
class RabProducts extends Pivot {
    //relation function to currency
}
```

and change my products model something like:

```
   public function rab(){
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\ModelUnitKerja\Perencanaan\RabModel')->using('App\RabProducts');
}
```

Comment: You have to create model for every table except the pivot ones. If currencies is a table, you have to create a model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create the currency model and add foreign_key `product_id`:

```sh
php artisan make:model Currency
```

2. Build the [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) between Product and Currency
   and you need to add `product_id` in your `currencies` table.

In your Currency Model:

```php
    public function product() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id');
    }
```

In your Product Model:

```php
    public function currencies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Currency::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }
```

So that you can call it like this:

```php
RAB::with(['products' => function($query) {
    $query->with('currencies');
}])->get();
```

Unfortunately, the foreign_key between `products` and `rabs` is in pivot table, you cannot create the `hasmanythrough` with currency directly.

You can call the currency by products. Or you can create a [pivot model](https://medium.com/@DarkGhostHunter/laravel-has-many-through-pivot-elegantly-958dd096db), and then use `hasmanythrough`.

Comment: thanks for fast reply.. will this currency associated with product's rab? need some explanation cause i'm new to this kind of relation..

Comment: @Aachan unfortunately, the foreign_key between products and rabs is in pivot table, you cannot create the `hasmanythrough` with currency directly. You can call the currency by products. Or you can create a [pivot model](https://medium.com/@DarkGhostHunter/laravel-has-many-through-pivot-elegantly-958dd096db), and then use hasmanythrough

Comment: can you add your comment to your answer? it makes more sense to me for accepting the answer.. thanks anyway!